# Can someone explain me why the print of only string s4 turns out to be 10bab?

Tags: java, concatenation

I am currently learning java for the first time and got stuck at certain peice of code. The exercise was on comments. The task was to comment out unnecessary part of code.

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 15;
        double c = b + 38;
        //int d = a + 12;
       // double e = 12.3;
        String s = "s" + a;
        String s1 = a + "b";
        //String s2 = "a";
        String s3 = s1 + "a";
        String s4 = s3 + "b";
        System.out.println(c + s4 + s);
    }
}
```

If i print only s4 the output turns out to be

```
10bab
```

Shouldn't the output for only printing s4 be 
`10151015`
as while printing string s1 the variable a and b both are called and concatenated. Or is it somewhere fault at my understanding.
Would appreciate your valuable time and answer.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are confusing `b` with `"b"`, one is a variable, the other is a string.

Comment: Same for `a` vs `"a"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are mixing the types which leeds you to missunderstanding.

int - responsible for storing whole numbers like 1, 2, 5

double - responsible for storing comma separated vales like 1.5, 6.3, 5.321

String - responsible for alphanumeric signs so it can store anything "Table", "2" (NOTE if im using "" it means that this is meant to be a String)

So going through your code the output of the code line by line is:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 15;
int c = b + 38; // OUTPUT 53
//int d = a + 12;
//double e = 12.3;
String s = "s" + a; // OUTPUT s10 COMMENT You are adding String "s" to int a so a become String with value of "10"
String s1 = a + "b"; // OUTPUT 10b COMMENT same story here a become String with value "10" and we are adding string "b"   
//String s2 = "a";                                                  
String s3 = s1 + "a"; // OUTPUT 10ba COMMENT s1 is now "10b" and you are adding "a"
String s4 = s3 + "b"; // OUTPUT 10bab COMMENT s3 is now "10ba" and you are adding "b"                                                
System.out.println(c + s4 + s); // OUTPUT 5310babs10 COMMENT c becomes String with value "53" adding s4 = "10ba" adding String s = "s10"
```

To achieve your expectations 10151015 the code should look like this

```
int a = 10;
int b = 15;
int c = b + 38; // OUTPUT 53
String s1 = String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b); // OUTPUT 1015
String s3 = s1 + String.valueOf(a); // OUTPUT 101510
String s4 = s3 + String.valueOf(b); // OUTPUT 10151015
```

I wasn't running that code but I hope you understand your wrong understanding :D

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There's is a rule in `java`:

```
int a = 10;
String str = a + "xxx"; // means str = String.valueOf(a) + "xxx"
```

---

```
int a = 10;                         // a == 10
int b = 15;                         // b == 15
double c = b + 38;                  // c == b + 38 = 15 + 38 = 53.0
//int d = a + 12;
// double e = 12.3;
String s = "s" + a;                 // s == "s" + a = "s" + "10" = "s10"
String s1 = a + "b";                // s1 == a + "b" = "10" + "b" = "10b"
//String s2 = "a";
String s3 = s1 + "a";               // s3 == s1 + "a" = "10b" + "a" = "10ba"
String s4 = s3 + "b";               // s4 == s3 + "b" = "10ba" + "b" = "10bab"
System.out.println(c + s4 + s);     // c + s4 + s = "53.0" + "10bab" + "s10" = "53.010babs10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`int a` is a variable where as `"a"` is a `String`. The variable `a` is only used in `String s1` (and `String s`), the other `String`s use `"a"` which won't be replaced by the value of `a`, because it is a string literal.

```
int a = 10;
String s1 = a + "b";
String s3 = s1 + "a";
String s4 = s3 + "b";
```

`String s4` will be:

```
10 + "b" + "a" + "b"
```

Comment: Oh i got it now. Thanks